# Service wait for other Service

Tags: android

I have a service A and B; Service A starts service B.

Service A:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Intent serviceB = new Intent(this, ServiceB.class);
    startService(serviceB);
    ...
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Service B:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"B",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    ...
}
```

This code shows Toast A and then shows Toast B. How can I make that Toast on Service A appears after Toast on Service B?

Comment: call `bindService` from service `A` and you will be notified via `ServiceConnection`

Comment: Or, better yet, get rid of Service B and combine them into one service.

Comment: @CommonsWare I can't combine them. I used a simple example but my code is more complex.

Comment: @pskink Can you give an example of how I can do that? Thanks.

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html